# New Relic RPM meaning?

Tags: newrelic

I know it stands for (requests per minute). What I want to know is the details on the calculation. How is it calculated? For example, I am seeing "3 minutes from 18:10 to 18:13 12.1k rpm" on the chart. But how is the number 12.1k computed? Do they include requests coming before 18:10 and finishing between 18:10 and 18:13, and requests coming between 18:10 and 18:13 and finishing after 18:13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Relic records Transactions and reports in minute poll cycles.  A single transaction will be recorded in the poll cycle that it ends in.

When you are looking at a three minute timeslice, the New Relic dashboard has aggregated three one minute poll cycles and will add all the transactions that ended in those poll cycles.